# Ignore empty cell array and execute the following cell

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, conditional-statements

I want to make a condition that check if the cell array is empty then move to the next.

I got this index exceed matrix dimensions

Looking forward to hear from you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isempty`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) to check if an element is empty or not:

```
C = cell(5,1);
C{2} = 2;

for ind = 1:length(C)
    if ~isempty(C{ind})
        disp(['Processing C{' num2str(ind) '}']);
    end
end
```

and never let index of `C` exceed `length(C)`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have applied almost similar to what you suggested but It is not working in the way I want it to work.. It trigger an error..


 Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in Senses (line 48)
senses = regexp(groupSenses{1}, [arrowSymbol '[\w, ]*\n '], 'match');

Comment: Can you confirm that `length(groupSenses)` is greater than `1`?

Comment: The groupSense is 1x0 cell... It is an empty cell

Comment: So `groupSenses{1}` does not exist. You are trying to access beyond `groupSenses` range. You should check the part you assign `groupSenses`.